# Can I create a self healing file or archive

Tags: security, backup, data-recovery, file-management

Earlier I backuped data to CD disks which get unusable after some years as CD get damaged (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption). So I made 2 or more copy of that data file so that even if some sectors damage they can be fixed with the another. Now I migrated from CD to cloud but network error is a problem.

So I'm looking for a file type or archive like .zip which automatically find and repare data corruption.

Comment: There exists an additional file format called PAR2 that does this.  You choose what percent of the file can be incomplete or corrupted.

Comment: Not sure if that's going to be useful. Your cloud provider probably uses hard disks and you're more likely to have a total loss rather than a partial one. My advice is to upload things twice to 2 different cloud providers.

Comment: PAR2 sounds good

Comment: @LatinSuD I believe OP's concern is not that the data disappears because the cloud provider experiences a failure, but that a network error could mess up the file upon downloading.